# Comparing every row in table with the master row

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, looker

I have a Redshift table with single VARCHAR column named "Test" and several float columns. The "Test" column has unique values, one of them is "Control", others are not hardcoded.

Tables has ~10 rows (not static) and ~10 columns.

I need to generate the Looker report which will show the original data and the difference between the corresponding float columns in "Control" and other Tests.
Input Example:

```
    Test | Metric_1 | Metric_2
  ---------------------------- 
  Control|    10     | 100
  A      |    12     | 120
  B      |    8      | 80
```

The desirable report:

```
         | Control | A  | A-Control | B | B-Control
         |---------|----|-----------|---|-----------
Metric_1 | 10      | 12 |    2      | 8 | -2
Metric_2 | 100     | 120|    20     | 80| -20
```

To calculate the difference for the each row with "Control"
I tried:

```
SELECT T.test, 
T.metric_1 - Control.metric_1 AS DIFF1,
T.metric_2 - Control.metric_2 AS DIFF2,
...
FROM T, (SELECT * FROM T WHERE test='Control') AS Control
```

I can do part of work in Looker (it can transpose), 
part in SQL, but still cannot figure out how to build this report.

Comment: Why can't you use the results of your query in Looker?  What is your question?  Is the problem transposing the data?  Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You could transpose the test dimension, being able to build part of it:

```
         | Control | A  | B |
         |---------|----|---|
Metric_1 | 10      | 12 | 8 |
Metric_2 | 100     | 120| 80|
```

Then operate on top of this results using table calculations. 
You can use the functions pivot_where() or pivot_index().
For example, pivot_where(test = 'A', metric) - pivot_where(test = 'Control', metric)